# Google Chrome history

Tags: google-chrome, privacy, history

There's a bug, I think, in the way Chrome manages its history.

When I clear the history with CCleaner, I can open Chrome and see that History is blank. However, as soon as I start browsing the web a bit, I go back to History and see tons of history from several weeks ago (though only the most frequent websites). This does not happen with History Eraser (the extension).

How can I get CCleaner to remove Chrome's history actually?

Comment: Just out of curiousity, why don't you clear it through Chrome's clear browsing data?

Comment: **^ edit:** chrome://settings/clearBrowserData

Answer (score 1):

> *It's not a bug, It's a feature*

When you are logged into your Google Account, Chrome will (by default) sync its history, settings, themes, extensions and some other things with Google servers. In other words, when you use Chrome, it detects that it is missing the local history data and will try to synchronize the missing data.

---

### Here is how you can delete Google Chrome's history properly

1. In the top-right corner of the browser window, click the Chrome menu button.
2. Click History and recent tabs > History.
3. Click the button Clear browsing data. A dialog will appear.
4. From the drop-down menu, select how much history you want to delete. To clear your entire browsing history, select the beginning of time.
   Check the boxes for the data you want Chrome to clear, including “**browsing history**."
5. Click the button Clear browsing data.

[(source)](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95589)

Comment: To answe the question, If you didn't delete the history through Chrome, Chrome has no way of knowing you deleted it, so, if the history is synced with any logged account, it will sync the missing data again.

TL:DR - Delete the history through Chrome itself.